# Probability - Independent Random Variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, summation, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables such that $X$~$U(1,n)$ and $Y$~$G(p)$ while $0<p<1, n \in \mathbb{N}$. What is the distribution of $X+Y$?

My attempt:

$$\begin{align}P(X+Y=k) &= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} P(X=i,Y=k-i) \\[1ex] &=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} P(X=i) \cdot P(Y=k-i) \\[1ex] &=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{n} \cdot (1-p)^{k-i-1}p\\[1ex]&=\frac{(1-p)^{k-1}p}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(1-p)^i} \\[1ex] &= \frac{(1-p)^{k-1}p}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1-p)^k}}{1-\frac{1}{1-p}}-1\right)\\[1ex]&=\end{align}$$

Is that Ok?

I do not know what to do next.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess $X$ is uniform _discrete._ In that case, $P(X = i) = 1/n.$

Comment: @WillM. You are right! Let me fix that here.

Comment: It seems correct, I don't see much more to do after changing the sum for the usual geometric sum formula. Just some minor algebraic simplifications.

Comment: What you wrote is only good for $k\le n$. For $k>n$ you might have $P(X=i)=0$

Comment: @Momo So do I need to separate it into 2 cases?

Comment: In principle, yes. You might get by with replacing $k-1$ with $\min(k-1,n)$ to get both cases into one formula.

Comment: @Momo Thank you, I will try!

Comment: @Momo For better understanding, if $P(X=i)=0$, then we get that $P(X+Y=k)=0$, is that correct?

Comment: You only get the specific terms of the sum zero, not the whole $P(X+Y=k)$